# How to get advice on where to post a question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, superuser

I am in the process of drawing together the information in order to ask a question about database driver generation and installation. I am not clear whether this is best suited to SO or SU. What criteria will help me choose the appropriate site?

Comment: Make the best call that you can, then let the community migrate it if they disagree. That's what migration is intended for. Too many people get offended when their post gets migrated; it's not a personal thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the FAQs of both websites but if I were you I wouldn't go further than that.. Deciding a website shouldn't be a really big complicated process.

If after reading the FAQs you still can't decide then pick a random one and post there, worst that can happen is your post is migrated. This is completely okay for borderline questions.